# Trying to match up strings in ""

Tags: regex, string, jflex

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
```

which I wish to match the pattern of the form

```
"testing"
```

But my regex is not matching any  of these strings. Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"[a-zA-Z0-9]*"`, not `"[a-zA-z0-9]*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your requirement is "matching" not "extracting":

```
^"[a-zA-Z0-9"]*"$ would be the regex you need.
```

note that since your 2nd example has nested double quotes, you need `"` in your `[]`

test with grep:

```
kent$  echo '"testing"
"testing123"hello""
'|grep -E '^"[a-zA-Z0-9"]*"$'
"testing"
"testing123"hello""
```

if you want to extract things between double quotes, you need to explain, what do you want to get in your 2nd example.

**EDIT**

if you just want to extract the things between double quote:

```
(?<=")[^"]*
```

is what you are looking for.

still testing with grep:

```
kent$  echo '"xxx bbb _ foo bar"'|grep -Po '(?<=")[^"]*'
xxx bbb _ foo bar
```

Comment: Sorry I need only to match the strings within the quotes. Second example I gave it wrong. Edited the question.

Comment: @GroovyUser check the edit in answer, if it is what u r looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have to escape the

```
"
```

with a

```
\
```

as in:

```
\"[a-zA-z0-9]*\"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you three matches as expected.

See this http://rubular.com/r/WW9IKTb0Xa